# How to implement two inits with same content without code duplication in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Assume a class that is derived from `UIView` as follows:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var myImageView: UIImageView

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    ...
```

If I wanted to have the same code in both of the initializers, like

```
self.myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

and **NOT duplicate that code** twice in the class implementation, how would I structure the `init` methods?

Tried approaches:

- Created a method `func commonInit()` that is called after `super.init` -> Swift compiler gives an error about an uninitialized variable `myImageView` before calling `super.init`
- Calling `func commonInit()` before `super.init` fails self-evidently with a compiler error *"'self' used before super.init call"*

Comment: I don't have it handy, but there's a discussion about this in the swift book.  Do a search for designated initialization or initializer and you should find it.

Comment: The Topic is probably called "Class Inheritance and Initialization".

Comment: This is no doubt one of the most annoying things in Swift. A problem I faced on day one, and one continues to bother me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051188/how-to-share-common-init-code-between-different-designated-init-methods?lq=1).

As GoZoner said, marking your variables as optional will work. It's not a very elegant way because you then have to unwrap the value each time you want to access it.

I will file an enhancement request with Apple, maybe we could get something like a "beforeInit" method that is called before every init where we can assign the variables so we don't have to use optional vars.

Until then, I will just put all assignments into a commonInit method which is called from the dedicated initialisers. E.g.:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?  // marked as optional, so it does not have to be assigned before super.init
    
    func commonInit() {
        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer!.frame = self.bounds
        // more setup 
    }
     
    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
     init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer!.frame = self.bounds  // unwrap explicitly because the var is marked optional
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to David I had a look at the book again and I found something which might be helpful for our deduplication efforts without having to use the optional variable hack. One can use a closure to initialize a variable.

> **Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function**
>
> If a stored property’s default value requires some customization or setup, you can use a closure or global function to provide a customized default value for that property. Whenever a new instance of the type that the property belongs to is initialized, the closure or function is called, and its return value is assigned as the property’s default value. These kinds of closures or functions typically create a temporary value of the same type as the property, tailor that value to represent the desired initial state, and then return that temporary value to be used as the property’s default value.
>
> Here’s a skeleton outline of how a closure can be used to provide a default property value:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass {
> let someProperty: SomeType = {
>     // create a default value for someProperty inside this closure
>     // someValue must be of the same type as SomeType
>     return someValue
>     }() 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the closure’s end curly brace is followed by an empty pair of parentheses. This tells Swift to execute the closure immediately. If you omit these parentheses, you are trying to assign the closure itself to the property, and not the return value of the closure.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l

This is the way I will use from now on, because it does not circumvent the useful feature of not allowing nil on variables. For my example it'll look like this:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        return CAGradientLayer()
    }()
    
    func commonInit() {
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        /* more setup */
    }
    
    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand your excellent explanation you can omit having the @lazy keyword when initialization is done by using closures?

Comment: The closures combined with `commonInit()` are exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Or just use the shorter form: `var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()` (or even shorter `var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()`) if you just want to allocate the object.

Answer (score 24):

What we need is a common place to put our initialization code before calling any superclass's initializers, so what I currently using, shown in a code below. (It also cover the case of interdependence among defaults and keep them constant.)

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {
        let value1: Int
        let value2: Int

        enum InitMethod {
                case coder(NSCoder)
                case frame(CGRect)
        }

        override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
                self.init(.frame(frame))!
        }

        required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                self.init(.coder(aDecoder))
        }

        private init?(_ initMethod: InitMethod) {
                value1 = 1
                value2 = value1 * 2 //interdependence among defaults

                switch initMethod {
                case let .coder(coder): super.init(coder: coder)
                case let .frame(frame): super.init(frame: frame)
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Very nice and clean. Only solution that preserves the `let` properties and keeps the property initialization and further setup together. You could clean it up further to better illustrate the solution by dropping `myImageView` and `InitMethod.Default`, and moving `InitMethod` into `MyView`.

Comment: No optional / IUO / var. This is brilliant.

Comment: Nice! But it's not working on Xcode 10.2 due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772103/2396171). I've added another answer that includes a workaround.

Comment: Aside from the Xcode 10.2 issue, `enum InitMethod` could be marked as `private`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
public class MyView : UIView
{
    var myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    private func setup()
    {
        myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that'll also do. It seems that a newer Xcode beta has introduced access control (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Comment: I've added what I consider the most likely required access control for the example at hand.

Comment: Yes, I have the GM now - I just realized they added the Access Controls in beta 4. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assign `myImageView` in both the `init()` methods based on a single image create function.  As such:

```
self.myImageView = self.createMyImageView ();
```

For example, like such:

```
class Bar : Foo {
    var x : Int?
    func createX () -> Int { return 1 }
    init () {
        super.init ()
        self.x = self.createX ()
    }   
}
```

Note the 'optional' use at `Int?`

Comment: The optional is the important part. Assigning the value via an method is superfluous. `self.x = 1` will work as well.

Comment: The point was to define a function `createX()` that would do complex stuff needed by multiple `init()` methods; the example did only the most simplistic thing - return `1`.

Comment: I'll mark Matthias Bauch's answer correct, because marking variables optional requires unwrapping the value every time you want to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it necessarily have to come before? I think this is one of the things implicitly unwrapped optionals can be used for:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var myImageView: UIImageView!

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    }

    ...
}
```

Implicitly unwrapped optionals allow you skip variable assignment before you call `super`. However, you can still access them like normal variables:

`var image: UIImageView = self.myImageView // no error`

Comment: Unfortunately the implicit unwrapped optional kills the benefit of not being able to assign nil or an optional to a variable that shouldn't be optional in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, good point. But IIRC, something like this was one of the examples given in the Swift book.

Comment: Also IUO's can lead to unexpected crashes if the code evolves and someone forgets to initialize the property.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option using a static method (added 'otherView' to highlight scalability)

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var myImageView: UIImageView
    var otherView: UIView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        (myImageView,otherView) = MyView.commonInit()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        (myImageView, otherView) = MyView.commonInit()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    private static func commonInit() -> (UIImageView, UIView) {
        //do whatever initialization stuff is required here
        let someImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
        someImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        let someView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        return (someImageView, someView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if the intention is to assign `myImageView` exactly once, it should be a `let` rather than a `var`. That rules out some solutions that only work for `var`.

Another complication is multiple instance variables with dependencies between them. This rules out inline initializers calling static methods.

These requirements can be addressed by overriding with convenience initializers, which delegate to a single designated initializer:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {
    let myImageView: UIImageView
    // Just to illustrate dependencies...
    let myContainerView: UIView
    
    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame, coder: nil)!
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Dummy value for `frame`
        self.init(frame: CGRect(), coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    @objc private init?(frame: CGRect, coder aDecoder: NSCoder?) {
        // All `let`s must be assigned before
        // calling `super.init`...
        myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        // Just to illustrate dependencies...
        myContainerView = UIView()
        myContainerView.addSubview(myImageView)
        
        if let aDecoderNonNil = aDecoder {
            super.init(coder: aDecoderNonNil)
        } else {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
        
        // After calling `super.init`, can safely reference
        // `self` for more common setup...
        self.someMethod()
    }

    ...    
}
```

This is based on [ylin0x81's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772103/2396171), which I really like but doesn't work now (build with Xcode 10.2), as load from nib crashes with:

```
This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:
```

This issue is covered on a separate question, with [iuriimoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56295144/2396171) suggesting to add `@objc` to the designated initializer. That entailed avoiding the Swift-only enum used by ylin0x81.