# How to share common init code between different designated init methods?

Tags: swift

In Objective-C I often move common init code into its own method, and then I call that method from the various designated initialisers of the class. Like this:

```
- (void)commonInit {
    _gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    /* ... */
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
```

In Swift this pattern does not work because you basically have to use a "two stage init". First you have to assign variables of your own subclass, then call `super.init` and only then you are allowed to access self. e.g.:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)  {
    // initial assignment must be done first
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    // no calls to self allowed
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // calls to self allowed
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    /* ... */
}
```

I can easily move the "second phase", the set up, which happens after `super.init` to its own method. However, I can't move the "first phase", the initial assignment to its own method because calling the method involves a call to self, which is not allowed before calling `super.init`.

Am I missing a way to move the initial assignment to its own method? I really don't want to duplicate all the assignments in the various init methods.

Comment: @matthiasbuch rather than flag your duplicate question, just delete it yourself :)

Comment: No. I'm one of those (few) people that think (some) duplicates are useful. I did search stackoverflow for ~10 minutes before asking. So I obviously used very different language to describe my problem, because I was not able to find the question before asking. So now we have two different routes to the same question and answer, which should help future visitors.