# How can I initialize a let variable using a shared init method?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to setup a variable using `let` so that its not optional, won't change over time and doesn't require messy unwrapping to access each time. I know I can legally set it, but only inside one of the `init` methods. The problem is that Swift requires you to override the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initializer. However I've never had an app that ever has that initializer called. Its always the `init(frame: CGRect)` initializer that is called. So if I didn't have to override `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` then I'd just do the `self.imageView = UIImageView.new()` in `init(frame: CGRect)` and I'd be done, but the compiler complains that its not set in the other init as well. I tried making a `sharedInit()` method that is called from both inits, but the compiler won't let me set the `imageView` from there since it's read only outside of the init methods. How are you supposed to accomplish this without doing all of your init twice directly in the init methods?

```
class SuperCoolView : UIView {

    let imageView: UIImageView

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        sharedInit()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        sharedInit()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func sharedInit() {
        self.imageView = UIImageView.new()
        // Other similar shared init
    }

}
```

Comment: Swift 1.2 kinda fixes this issue (you can set the let variable anywhere but of course only once..).

Comment: I'm doing this in Xcode 6.3b3 so I'm using Swift 1.2, and I'm getting errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement two inits with same content without code duplication in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24023412/1445366). See [this answer in particular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24051352/1445366) - you can combine closure-based property initialization with a `commonInit()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128815/253456) and liked it's approach. It fixed the problem, and is much cleaner IMHO. By implementing `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` normally we would be keeping up the appearance that this view can be initialized from a nib/storyboard when it can't.

```
class SuperCoolView : UIView {

let imageView: UIImageView

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    self.imageView = UIImageView.new()
    // Other stuff
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just use a combination of lazy initialization and private 'set' to get:

```
class SuperCoolView : UIView {
  public private(set) lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    // In practice, do more here.  Access state in this instance.
    // Or, include more computation.
    UIImageView.new()
  }()

  // inits w/o setting imageView
}
```

The 'private set' makes this externally identical to a `let`; the `lazy` lets you initialize the value based on the other state in the `SuperCoolView` instance.

Note that if the initialization of imageView, and others, doesn't depend on state in the instance, then you can avoid the `lazy` and just do the initialization from the closure.

Comment: Why not just use `let imageView = UIImageView()`? Or the closure-based `let` initialization in the answer I linked to?

Comment: I updated.  Our updates crossed.  Yes, if the assignment doesn't depend on complex computation or state in `SuperCoolView`, then you can just assign it.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using closures on property declarations. This makes reading the code later much more complex. I prefer that the top of the swift file just be the public methods/properties with as little implementation details as possible. I really miss header files for this purpose.

Comment: So you prefer 'named closures' (like `sharedInit`) over 'anonymous closures'?  Your opinion will change grasshopper!  :-)

Comment: No, I just prefer to place something like `sharedInit` down "hidden" in the implementation details of the class, not tied to the public property declaration.