# Common init when using constants

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Utilizing constants in subclasses with lot of initializers to override is tedious. Look at the class below, I need to duplicate the code in both initializers.

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview: UIView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        subview = UIView() // once
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        subview = UIView() // twice
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

If I try to make use of a common initializer then I get the following errors (see the comments)

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    commonInit() // 1: Use of 'self' in method call 'commonInit' before super.init initializes self
    super.init(frame: frame) // 2: Property 'self.subview' is not in initialized at super.init call
}

private func commonInit() {
    subview = UIView() // 3: Cannot assign to 'subview' in 'self'
}
```

It works fine if I do not use a constant and define the subview like:

```
var subview: UIView?
```

And then of course switch order in init like this:

```
super.init(frame: frame)
commonInit()
```

So my question: is there no way to use a common initializer for constants in Swift as of now?

**EDIT: I totally forgot to mention that the struggle here is that I can't initiate the subview before I'm in the init, it's initiated based on data that is not known when declaring the constant.**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023412/how-to-implement-two-inits-with-same-content-without-code-duplication-in-swift ?

Comment: No, as I have stated I know how to do this for var, I'm using let

Comment: See my answer below.  It allows you to initialize values correctly based on context.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview:UIView

    init(frame: CGRect?, coder: NSCoder?) {

        // The first phase initialization here
        subview = UIView()

        if let frame = frame {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
        else if let coder = coder {
            super.init(coder: coder)
        }
        else {
            super.init()
        }

        // the Second phase initialization here
        self.addSubview(subview)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: nil, coder: nil)
    }

    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame, coder: nil)
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(frame: nil, coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

A little bit cleaner alternative:

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview:UIView

    private enum SuperInitArg {
        case Frame(CGRect), Coder(NSCoder), None
    }

    private init(_ arg: SuperInitArg) {

        subview = UIView()

        switch arg {
        case .Frame(let frame): super.init(frame:frame)
        case .Coder(let coder): super.init(coder:coder)
        case .None: super.init()
        }

        addSubview(subview)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(.None)
    }
    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(.Frame(frame))
    }
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(.Coder(aDecoder))
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still struggling whether to close the question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023412/how-to-implement-two-inits-with-same-content-without-code-duplication-in-swift, which has a similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26772103/1187415 (even if your's looks a bit cleaner).

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that answer. At least, my answer is definitely a dupe of that.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview = UIView()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //edit subview properties as needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is following the *Xcode* pattern:

```
class Test : UIView {

    var subview: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        subview = UIView()
    }
}
```

Notice your `subview` is a `var`

Another option is:

```
class Test : UIView {

    let subview: UIView = {
        let sv = UIView()
        // some config, (i.e.: bgColor etc., frame is not yet _real_
        // can't yet access instance's frame and other properties
        return sv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        // frame might be valid, preferably use layout constraints
        addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `subview` is initialized even before `super.init()` is called, that's not really "lazy" :) – Perhaps you meant `lazy var subview: UIView = ...` (but then it is not constant anymore).

Comment: @MartinR you are right, my use of _lazy_ was misleading. I meant _lazy commonInit()_ :-/ Edited it, hope it is more clear what I intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
// Declare this somewhere (it can be used by multiple classes)
class FrameCoder: NSCoder {
    let frame: CGRect
    init(_ frame: CGRect) {
        self.frame = frame
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Then, when you want a common initializer pattern, use this:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let something: SomeType

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if (aDecoder is FrameCoder) {
            super.init(frame: (aDecoder as! FrameCoder).frame)
        }
        else {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        // Common initializer code goes here...
        something = // some value
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(coder: FrameCoder(frame))
    }
}
```

The advantage of using this method is you don't need to create default values for `let` definitions -- you can set them to the correct values in context, just like you would if there were only a single initializer.

Note that you can use this technique for initializers taking arbitrary values (not just for `init(frame: CGRect)`) -- you can create a specific NSCoder subclass to wrap any value and type you need to pass to an initializer, and then chain it into your `init(coder:)` method.

(also, there's probably some way to do this with a generic... haven't quite figured that out yet!  Anyone...?)