# This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application is working fine with iOS 11.2 but in iOS 11.3 is going crash. i got exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder

I have one viewController with tableView and this tableView have 2 cells somehow this table view can't able to load a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

```
LPDiscoverFeedCell *cell = (LPDiscoverFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:checkPortrait];
```

this is exception point where i got this.

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 10.2 updated compiler with new feature:

> To reduce the size taken up by Swift metadata, convenience
> initializers defined in Swift now only allocate an object ahead of
> time if they’re calling a designated initializer defined in
> Objective-C. In most cases, this has no effect on your app, but if
> your convenience initializer is called from Objective-C and doesn’t in
> turn delegate via self.init to an initializer exposed to Objective-C,
> the initial allocation from alloc is released without any initializer
> being called. This can be problematic for users of the initializer
> that don’t expect any sort of object replacement to happen. One
> instance of this is with initWithCoder:: the implementation of
> NSKeyedUnarchiver may behave incorrectly if it calls into Swift
> implementations of initWithCoder: and the archived object graph
> contains cycles. To avoid this, ensure that convenience initializers
> that don’t support object replacement always delegate to initializers
> that are also exposed to Objective-C, either because they’re defined
> in Objective-C, or because they’re marked with @objc, or because they
> override initializers exposed to Objective-C, or because they satisfy
> requirements of an @objc protocol. (46823518)"
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2?language=objc

I had MyClass in Storyboard scene:

[image]

If MyClass has convenience init() which calls designated initializer, then it should be marked with @objc:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    override convenience init() {
        self.init(int: 42)
    }

    // Add @objc to stop crashes
    @objc init(int: Int) {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it for me. :) Great answer. I was completely at a loss.

Comment: Great answer for anyone interesting in injecting `Foundation` types.  In my case, I wanted to inject an custom object conforming to a protocol in the scenario you outlined and the above solution didn't work until I marked my protocol with `@objc`.

Answer (score 3):

I started seeing this crash once i updated my xcode from 10.0 to 10.2.1

The issue was present in the "InputMask" library version 4.1.0 and the issue has been fixed in its version 4.1.1. I was using carthage, so, all I had to do was run *carthage update* command

For more information on the commit that fixed crash, here is the link:

[NSGenericException: This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395414/nsgenericexception-this-coder-requires-that-replaced-objects-be-returned-from-i/56001257#56001257)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it works after turning off the "Prefers coder at runtime" in IB.

[image]

Comment: This was the reason for a macOS app, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the `LPDiscoverFeedCell`? If not, Please try this,

Option 1

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[LPDiscoverFeedCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"checkPortrait"];
```

Option 2

```
UINib *feedCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"LPDiscoverFeedCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:feedCell forCellReuseIdentifier:@"checkPortrait"];
```

And see if this resolves the issue.