# Swift error from required convenience for viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm playing around with having a factory that sets up a login in a view controller to satisfy myself what is going on (this is old code I'm updating) I'm trying to make this as simple an example as possible.

It crashes!

View Controller

```
init(loginServerClass: String){
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

//called to initialize the login server class
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder, loginServerClass: String){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

//called from storyboard
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

using a LoginFactory

```
public protocol LoginFactoryProtocol{
    static func createLogin () -> String
}

class LoginFactory : LoginFactoryProtocol {

    static public func createLogin () -> String {
        return "testlogintype"
    }
}
```

So 
1). It crashes with the minimal example above (bad access)

2). It crashes when I add my prefered convenience int as below:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(coder: aDecoder, loginServerClass: LoginFactory.createLogin() )
}
```

(This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:)

How can I compile this minimum code?

Github link https://github.com/stevencurtis/initissue

If downvoters could explain why, that would be appreciated as I can't improve without knowing what needs to be added. I already added the error messages, a Github link with the problem. I've listed what I've tried, and I'm going from existing previously working code to a small example (therefore I HAVE tried things, the documentation is https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324 and similar questions on stack overflow have not helped (they seem to have the same issues i.e. ([NSGenericException: This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395414/nsgenericexception-this-coder-requires-that-replaced-objects-be-returned-from-i)))). By definition this is a small example of the problem. I believe this is how a question should be structured (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so please do tell me: what else do I need to do to write a good question, please?

Comment: What are the details of the crash - there should be an exception message.  What line does it crash on.

Comment: Just tried with your sample code and it's not crashing for me. Please provide more details.

Comment: self.init(coder: aDecoder) EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Crashes for me every time

Comment: If downvoters could explain why, that would be appreciated as I can't improve without knowing what needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (and I don't know if it is good practice) seems to be to use a single initializer that calls super.init

```
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    loginServerClass = LoginFactory.createLogin()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

and then have a single intializer for testing and mocking (or to create the viewcontroller otherwise from code)

```
init(loginServerClass: String){
    self.loginServerClass = loginServerClass
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```